# openSuSE Custom Kernel Module Failed

Tags: module, kernel, opensuse

I am trying to port my own kernel module from CentOS to openSuSE, but it seems that my module can not load correctly on openSuSE. The OS give the following response:
[image]

But if I go directly to the ko compile dir, I can insert the module, like this:
[image]

So I don't know if there is some problem with my kernel module installation script or something else?
Here is my kernel installation script, and it work well in CentOS:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)

include Kbuild

else

KDIR ?= /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build

default:

$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD

endif

install:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD modules_install
clean:
    rm *.o *.ko .*.cmd *.mod.c
```

Comment: My openSuSE version is 13.2, and kernel version is 3.16.7-35-default

Comment: Add this information into your question post via [edit].